# Geometric Median and Voronoi Diagrams

Tags: computational-geometry

Is there a relationship between Voronoi Diagrams and the geometric median? I know that it is impossible to find a closed expression for the geometric median, but the two concepts seem related.

Comment: Could you clarify why the two concepts seem related?